# Inheritance of function parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I was wondering how can I correctly override the function of derived class with a derived function parameter?
e.g.

```
struct X;
struct Y:X
struct Z:X

class A {
    public:
      int f(int, X);    
};

class B : A{
    public:
       int f(int, Y);
};

class C : A{
    public:
       int f(int, Z);
};
```

Comment: if it were possible, consider passing an X to an A whose dynamic type is B, what should the call resolve to ?

Comment: You cannot as it would be wrong. Contra-variance is not supported, only co-variance on return type is supported.

Comment: @Jarod42 but only covariance on return of reference and pointer and base derived relationships, which is a subst of covariance.

Comment: wiKon, your code has no overriding as overriding only occurs with `virtual` methods, beyond your request for contra variance.  It is really really hard to read someone's mind when they cannot express what they want in code.  Always try to create a valid compiling example, then do minimal editing of your code to describe what you want to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that you can substitude derived/base classes for return values/parameters is known as covariant return types and contravariant arguments.

In C++, reference and pointer return types of `virtual` pointers have covariant overloading in derived types; you can return a more restricted (pointer or reference) to the base return type in derived types.

Contravariance of arguments, where you replace a `Derived*` argument in base interface with a `Base*` argument in derived, isn't supported in C++, but you can emulate it with both overloading and overriding.

```
struct BaseValue {};
struct DerivedValue:BaseValue {};
struct MoreDerivedValue:DerivedValue {};

struct BaseInterface {
  virtual void contra_example( DerivedValue* ptr ) = 0;
  virtual DerivedValue* co_example() = 0;
  virtual ~BaseInterface() {}
};

struct DerivedInterface:BaseInterface {
  virtual void contra_example( DerivedValue* ptr ) override final {
    contra_example( static_cast<Value*>( ptr ) );
  }
  void contra_example( Value* ptr ) override = 0;

  virtual MoreDerivedValue* co_example() override = 0;
};
```

`co_example` is an example of covariance in return type.  The compiler does this automatically for us in the case where we are just doing covariance based off of pointers and references into a type heirarchy.

`contra_example` is an example of contravariance of argument type.  `ptr`, the argument to `contra_example`, in the case of `DerivedInterface` can be any `Value*`.  The base interface requires that it be a `DerivedValue*`.

We can override the base `contra_example`, then forward to our internal "more accepting" implementation which is an *overload* in `DerivedInterface`.

The derived interface is *more permissive* than the base interface, and it provides guarantees *at least as good, or better* than the original does.

---

Now lets get back to your question.  First, no, the compiler won't do it for you.

Second, your logic is flawed.  Using the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), your `B` must be able to substitude for an `A`.

But your `B` has a *more restricted* contract on its argument to `f` than `A` does.  `A` requires an `X` argument, `B` requires that it be not only an `X` but a `Y` as well.

```
struct X1{};
struct X2{};
struct Y:X1,X2{};

struct A {
  virtual void foo( Y* ) = 0;
  virtual ~A() {}
}
struct B1:A {
  virtual void foo( Y* ptr ) final override { foo( static_cast<X1*>(ptr) ); }
  virtual void foo( X1* ) = 0;
}
struct B2:A {
  virtual void foo( Y* ptr ) final override { foo( static_cast<X2*>(ptr) ); }
  virtual void foo( X2* ) = 0;
}
```

this corresponds to your example.  The derived interfaces are more permissive of their (implicitly input) argument.

You can jump through hoops to have out-only arguments that support covariance, or simply return them.